# How does F# infer types and tags from other modules?

Tags: types, f#, type-inference, f#-4.0

Here is a minimal code example I use to explain my problem. The following code is organised in two files and compiles alright:

DataStruct.fs

```
module MyMod 
type XXX = {
    a: int
}
with
    static member GetNew =
        {
            a = -1
        }

type YYY = {
    a: float
}
with
    static member GetNew =
        {
            a = -1.0
        }


type Choice =
    | XXX of XXX
    | YYY of YYY
```

Program.fs

```
open MyMod

let generator = 
    let res = XXX.GetNew
    Choice.XXX res

let myVal : XXX = 
    match generator with
    | XXX x -> x
    | _ -> printfn "expected XXX, got sth else!"; XXX.GetNew
```

The interesting thing is that I have a Choice type that has two tags named the same way as the types they are tagging. This is, as far as I understand, a common convention in F#.

Now I change DataStruct such that I put it in a namespace and make MyMod just one of the modules in that namespace. Accordingly, in Program.fs I open the namespace and use everything prefixed with the module name:

DataStruct.fs

```
namespace DataStruct

module MyMod =
    type XXX = {
        a: int
    }
    with
        static member GetNew =
            {
                a = -1
            }

    type YYY = {
        a: float
    }
    with
        static member GetNew =
            {
                a = -1.0
            }


    type Choice =
        | XXX of XXX
        | YYY of YYY
```

Program.fs

```
open DataStruct

let generator = 
    let res = MyMod.XXX.GetNew
    MyMod.Choice.XXX res

let myVal : MyMod.XXX = 
    match generator with
    | MyMod.XXX x -> x
    | _ -> printfn "expected XXX, got sth else!"; MyMod.XXX.GetNew
```

Now Program.fs contains two errors. In the two lines where I try to call GetNew it says: "The field, constructor or member 'GetNew' is not defined"
This is because MyMod.XXX is inferred to be a union case of type MyMod.Choice.

Now without changing any of the structure of my code, I simply rename the Choice tags to be different from the types that they represent and everything works fine again.

DataStruct.fs as above but with

```
type Choice =
    | TX of XXX
    | TY of YYY
```

Program.fs

```
open DataStruct

let generator = 
    let res = MyMod.XXX.GetNew
    MyMod.Choice.TX res

let myVal : MyMod.XXX = 
    match generator with
    | MyMod.TX x -> x
    | _ -> printfn "expected XXX, got sth else!"; MyMod.XXX.GetNew
```

Now the call to GetNew is legal since the MyMod.XXX is correctly inferred to be the type I intended to use.

The question is now: is the issue described above a bug or feature of F#?
Or put differently, while it is advised to use the same names for tags and their types it seems to be a problem for the type inference mechanism. So is the advice a bad one or am I using namespaces, modules, types and tags in a bad way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is a bug in the compiler. The issue is related to another bug in the compiler, where discriminated union types are shadowing other type definitions in the same module, [see this bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1253). In the code you had posted: The root cause of the bug is [here](https://github.com/forki/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/nameres.fs#L1653) in the name resolution. `MyMod.XXX` is identified as a valid expression that refers to a DU type. This search is done greedily, the [codepath that searches for alternative resolutions](https://github.com/forki/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/nameres.fs#L1658) is not executed.

I've submitted bug reports [in visualfsharp](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1294) and [fsharp](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/580)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I hope this will be fixed soon. And I'm surprised a bit that not many more people have stumbled over this since such kind of use of discriminated union will appear frequently in F#, I believe.

Comment: @FriedrichGretz: thanks for the confirmation. Satisfactory for the bounty?

Answer (score 5):

The difference between your first and second piece of code is how you open the module in `Program.fs`:

- In your first code, by writing `open MyMod`, you open the module
- In your second version, by writing `open DataStruct`, you only open the namespace, but *not yet* the module. If you change that to `open DataStruct.MyMod`, you will get exactly the same behaviour as in the first version.

My rough explanation of what is going on:

- With the module open, F# sees two `XXX` floating around, and is able to disambiguate based on use.
- When you qualify with the module name, you are restricting `XXX` to be the latest type `XXX` that is defined in `MyMod`. The first `XXX` is your record, the second is a class derived from `Choice` that is also called `XXX`. Have a look at your assembly in something like ILSpy, for example.

UPDATE: Second paragraph is was incorrect. When qualified with the module name, the F# compiler incorrectly restricts `XXX` to be a DU type, shadowing the record type. See my second answer for more details.

Comment: Regarding the second point of your explanation: in the line "let myVal : MyMod.XXX" the XXX is correctly recognized as the type which contradicts that only the later declared MyMod.Choice.XXX is visible as XXX.

Comment: You're right, that's inconsistent with my explanation. Let me dig a little further.